# Yii2: How to stop view(page) calling by unauthorized person through Url

Tags: yii2

I am basically a PHP developer & learning Yii2. I am working on web application that has account based login system. Like the way i was doing in PHP web applications, i want to stop anonymous person from accessing the dashboard view if he/she is not authenticated. Its like if someone tries to access url(any related URL) externally:

```
www.example.com/staging/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/dashboard
```

At that time that person should be redirected to login page as that person is not authorized to access account based page directly.

What are the directions to implement this in MVC framework???

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 has action filter called [AccessControl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html) for this purposes. Attach it in `behaviors()` in your `SiteController`.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['dashboard'],
                    'roles' => ['@'], // allow only authenticated users
                ],
            ],
        ];
    ];
}
```

Now if guest user will try to access `site/dashboard` page he will be automaticaly redirected to `site/login` page.